# How to check java bit version on Linux?

Tags: java, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [installed jvm is 64 bit or 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574090/installed-jvm-is-64-bit-or-32-bit)

How do I check which bit version of Java is installed on my linux machine? When I type:

```
java -version
```

I get:

```
java version "1.6.0_16"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_16-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 14.2-b01, mixed mode)
```

Is that 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: What do you need to know it for?  Native code?

Comment: IIRC, 64-bit JVMs always explicitly mention the fact in their version output.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Run `java` with `-d64` or `-d32` specified, it will give you an error message if it doesn't support 64-bit or 32-bit respectively. Your JVM may support both.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you examine `System.getProperty("os.arch")` value in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [JVM online test](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/testvm.xml) and run it.

Then check the architecture displayed: x86_64 means you have the 64bit version installed, otherwise it's 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

Works for every binary, not only java:

```
file - < $(which java) # heavyly bashic

cat `which java` | file - # universal
```

Comment: This doesn't tell you if the JVM in question actually supports loading 64bit bytecodes.

Comment: There is no 32 or 64bits bytecode, it is the same. `float` and `int` are 32bits, `double` and `long` are 64bits on both architecture.