# Why Java VM won't initialize 2GB when I have 16GB RAM? Other machine works just fine

Tags: java, jmeter, heap-size

I've a 64 bit Windows 7 machine with 16GB RAM.

When I try to edit "jmeter.bat" to allocate more than 1GB heap size (e.g., set HEAP=-Xms1g -Xmx2g) and double click it, it gives me error that during initialization of VM it could not reserve enough space for object heap.

Interesting thing is: I've another machine with the same configuration (64 bit Windows 7 machine with 16GB RAM) where I am initializing JMeter with 10GB of heap size and it works!

Can anyone please help me explaining why? How can I avoid this error?

Thanks in advance.
--Ishti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that your java version is a 64 bit one.

Run:

> java -version

Comment: It says: 

java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: @IshtiaqueHussain no mention of it being 64-bit [probably means it isn't](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4574106).

Comment: Thanks guys! @UBIKLOADPACK, eager to get up/answer votes, huh? Just kidding, I'd expect the same. That was the problem. Default download gets 32-bit version! I went to oracle.com and download section and manually chose 64-bit version of it, installed it and now it works!

Comment: as a user of SO, When I don't know a subject I trust the green ok and upvote. If all answers stay without being validated then users don't know if they can trust answer, it also impacts negatively the tag statistics saying questions are unanswered, and also I think it's a minimum to reward somebody far from you who helped you :). If you look at our answers unfortunately there is a huge number which is ok but users didn't validate nor upvote